# Copy Azure KeyVault secrets from one Vault to Another using Powershell, supporting all characters

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I need to migrate secrets stored in Azure KeyVault from one vault to another.

I have a script which almost works; however, some of the passwords have an & in them, causing the secret not to be written in full. It writes the secret up to the & but omits anything after.

I've tried to escape the & but this doesn't seem to work.

The error I get is:

> '19!7e' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

This is the content of the secret, after the &.

What do I need to modify?

```
Param(
    [string] $originVault = 'a',
    [string] $originSubscriptionId = 'b',
    [string] $destinationVault = 'c',
    [string] $destinationSubscriptionId = 'd',
    [string] $disableDestinationSecrets = $true
)

# 1. Set the source subscription id. 
Write-Host "Setting origin subscription to: $($originSubscriptionId)..."
az account set -s $originSubscriptionId

# 1.1 Get all secrets
Write-Host "Listing all origin secrets from vault: $($originVault)"
$originSecretKeys = az keyvault secret list --vault-name $originVault  -o json --query "[].name"  | ConvertFrom-Json

# 1.3 Loop secrets into PSCustomObjects
$secretObjects = $originSecretKeys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host " - Getting secret value for '$($_)'"
    $secret = az keyvault secret show --name $_ --vault-name $originVault -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        secretName  = $_;
        secretValue = $secret.value;
    }#endcustomobject.

}#endforeach.

Write-Host "Done fetching secrets..."

# 2. Set the destination subscription id.
Write-Host "Setting destination subscription to: $($destinationSubscriptionId)..."
az account set -s $destinationSubscriptionId

# 2.2 Loop secrets objects, and set secrets in destination vault
Write-Host "Writing all destination secrets to vault: $($destinationVault)"

#doesn't work
# $secretObjects | ForEach-Object {
#     Write-Host " - Setting secret value for '$($_.secretName)'"
#     az keyvault secret set --vault-name $destinationVault --name "$($_.secretName)" --value  "$($_.secretValue)" --disabled $disableDestinationSecrets -o none
# }

##also doesn't work
$secretObjects | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host " - Setting secret value for '$($_.secretName)'"
    $escapedSecretValue = $_.secretValue -replace '&', '``&'
    az keyvault secret set --vault-name $destinationVault --name "$($_.secretName)" --value "$escapedSecretValue" --disabled $disableDestinationSecrets -o none
}

# 3. Clean up
Write-Host "Cleaning up and exiting."
Remove-Variable secretObjects
Remove-Variable originSecretKeys

Write-Host "Finished."
```

Credit to the original author:
https://zimmergren.net/backup-azure-key-vault-secrets-keys-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Please enclose the secret value in single quotes (') in the command instead of (").

So, your command could be like that

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name $destinationVault --name "$($_.secretName)" --value '$($_.secretValue)' --disabled $disableDestinationSecrets -o none
```

Comment: sorry, with single quote the error is now
--disabled was unexpected at this time.
The secret isn't written at all.